# Jetpack Compose Navigation loads screen infinitely

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, infinite-loop, jetpack-compose-navigation, compose-recomposition

I am trying to implement `Navigation` using single activity and
multiple `Composable` Screens.

This is my `NavHost`:

```
@Composable
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
fun MyNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = HOME.route,
    viewModelProvider: ViewModelProvider,
    speech: SpeechHelper
) = NavHost(
    modifier = modifier,
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = startDestination
) {
    composable(route = HOME.route) {
        with(viewModelProvider[HomeViewModel::class.java]) {
            HomeScreen(
                speech = speech,
                viewModel = this,
                modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent { handleKeyEvent(it, this) }
            ) {
                navController.navigateTo(it)
            }
        }
    }

    composable(route = Destination.VOLUME_SETTINGS.route) {
        VolumeSettingsScreen(
            viewModelProvider[VolumeSettingsViewModel::class.java]
        ) { navController.navigateUp() }
    }
}

fun NavHostController.navigateTo(
    navigateRoute: String,
    willGoBackTo: String = HOME.route
): Unit = navigate(navigateRoute) {
    popUpTo(willGoBackTo) { inclusive = true }
}
```

My screen looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    speech: SpeechHelper,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier,
    onNavigationRequested: (String) -> Unit
) {

    MyBlindAssistantTheme {
        val requester = remember { FocusRequester() }
        val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(
            initialValue = UiState.Speak(
                R.string.welcome_
                    .withStrResPlaceholder(R.string.text_home_screen)
                    .toSpeechUiModel()
            )
        )

        uiState?.let {
            when (it) {
                is UiState.Speak -> speech.speak(it.speechUiModel)
                is UiState.SpeakRes -> speech.speak(it.speechResUiModel.speechUiModel())
                is UiState.Navigate -> onNavigationRequested(it.route) 
            }
        }

        Column(
            modifier
                .focusRequester(requester)
                .focusable(true)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            val rowModifier = Modifier.weight(1f)

            Row(rowModifier) {...}
                   
        }

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            requester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mutableUiState: MutableStateFlow<UiState?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val uiState = mutableUiState.asStateFlow()

    
    fun onNavigateButtonClicked(){
        mutableUiState.tryEmit(Destination.VOLUME_SETTINGS.route.toNavigationState())
    }
}
```

When a button is clicked the `ViewModel` is called and the NavigateUiState is emitted... but it keeps being emitted after the next screen is loaded and that causes infinite screen reloading. What should be done to avoid this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I re-implemented your posted code with 2 screens, `HomeScreen` and `SettingScreen` and stripped out some part of the `UiState` class and its usages.

The issue is in your `HomeScreen` composable, not in the `StateFlow` emission.

You have this `mutableState`

```
val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(
      initialValue = UiState.Speak
)
```

that is being `observed` in one of your `when` block that executes a `navigation` callback.

```
uiState?.let {
         when (it) {
             is UiState.Navigate ->  {
                  onNavigationRequested(it.route)
             }
             UiState.Speak -> {
                 Log.d("UiState", "Speaking....")
            }
}
```

When your `ViewModel` function is called

```
 fun onNavigateButtonClicked(){
        mutableUiState.tryEmit(UiState.Navigate(Destination.SETTINGS_SCREEN.route))
 }
```

it will update `uiState`, setting its value to `Navigate`, observed by `HomeScreen`, satisfies the `when` block and then triggers the callback to navigate to the next screen.

Now based on the official [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation),

> You should only call navigate() as part of a callback and not as part
> of your composable itself, to avoid calling navigate() on every
> recomposition.

but in your case, the `navigation` is triggered by an observed `mutableState`, and the `mutableState` is part of your `HomeScreen` composable.

It seems like when the `navController` performs a navigation and the `NavHost` being a `Composable`

```
@Composable
public fun NavHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    route: String? = null,
    builder: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit
) { ... }
```

it will execute a `re-composition`, because of it, it will call again the `HomeScreen` (HomeScreen is not `re-composed`, its state remains the same) and because the `HomeScreen's` `UiState` value is still set to `Navigate`, it satisfies the `when` block, triggers again the callback to navigate, and `NavHost` `re-composes`, an **infinite cycle** is then created.

What I did (and its very **ugly**) is I created a `boolean` flag inside the viewModel, used it to wrap the callback conditionally,

```
uiState?.let {
            when (it) {
                is UiState.Navigate  ->  {
                    if (!viewModel.navigated) {
                        onNavigationRequested(it.route)
                        viewModel.navigated = true
                    } else {
                        // dirty empty else 
                    }
                }
                UiState.Speak -> {
                    Log.d("UiState", "Speaking....")
                }
            }
        }
```

and setting it to `true` afterwards, preventing the cycle.

I can hardly guess your compose implementation structure but I usually don't mix my one-time event actions and UiState, instead I have a separate `UiEvent` sealed class that will group "one-time" events such as the following:

> - Snackbar
> - Toast
> - Navigation

and having them emitted as a `SharedFlow` emissions because these events doesn't need any initial state or initial value.

Continuing further, I created this class

```
sealed class UiEvent {
    data class Navigate(val route: String) : UiEvent()
}
```

use it in the `ViewModel` as a type (`Navigate` in this case),

```
 private val _event : MutableSharedFlow<UiEvent> = MutableSharedFlow()
 val event = _event.asSharedFlow()

 fun onNavigateButtonClicked(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _event.emit(UiEvent.Navigate(Destination.SETTINGS_SCREEN.route))
        }
    }
```

and observe it in `HomeScreen` this way via `LaunchedEffect`, triggering the navigation in it without the callback being bound to any observed state.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.event.collectLatest {
            when (it) {
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                    onNavigationRequested(it.route)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This approach doesn't introduce the infinite navigation cycle and the dirty boolean checking is not needed anymore.

Also have a look this [S.O post, similar to your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71225637/jetpack-compose-navigation-infinite-loop-on-navigate)