# Jetpack Compose , mutable state causes infinite recomposition when navigating with NavHost

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation, compose-recomposition

Here is the code that causes the infinite recomposition problem

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        setContent {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                val viewModel : MainViewModel by viewModel()
                val state by viewModel.state.observeAsState()

                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "firstScreen") {
                    composable("firstScreen") { FirstScreen(
                        navigate = {
                        navController.navigate("secondScreen")
                    }, updateState = {
                            viewModel.getState()
                       },
                       state

                    )}

                    composable("secondScreen") { SecondScreen() }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    //var state = MutableStateFlow(0)

    private val _state = MutableLiveData(0)
    val state: LiveData<Int> = _state

    fun getState()  {
        _state.value = 1
    }
}
```

First Screen

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(
    navigate: () -> Unit,
    updateState: () -> Unit,
    state: Int?
) {

    Log.e("state",state.toString())

    Button(onClick = {
        updateState()
    }) {
        Text(text = "aaaaaaaa")
    }

    if(state == 1) {
        Log.e("navigate",state.toString())
        navigate()
    }
}
```

Second Screen

```
@Composable
fun SecondScreen() {...}
```

Pressing the button changes the state in the view model and in reaction if it changes to 1 it triggers navigation to the second screen but the first screen is infinitely recomposed and blocks the whole process

**Edit**

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(
    navigate: () -> Unit,
    updateState: () -> Unit,
    state: Int?
) {


    Log.e("state",state.toString())

    Button(onClick = {
        updateState()
    }) {
        Text(text = "aaaaaaaa")
    }

    LaunchedEffect(state) {

        if (state == 1) {
            Log.e("navigate", state.toString())
            navigate()
        }
    }

}
```

this solved the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are navigating based on a conditional property which is part of your `FirstScreen` composable and changes to that property are outside of the `FirstScreen's` scope, if that conditional property's value doesn't change, it will always evaluate its block every time the `NavHost` updates, in your case `state` remains `1` and will always executes its block.

```
if(state == 1) {
    ...
    navigate() // navigation
}
```

What you experience can be summarized by the events broken down below:

- Navhost configures `FirstScreen` and `SecondScreen` (initial `NavHost` `composition`)
- `FirstScreen` observes an integer `state` with a value of `0`
- `state` becomes `1` after you click the button
- `FirstScreen` `re-composes`, satisfies the condition (`state==1`), executes navigation for the **`1st`** time
- NavHost `re-composes`
- `FirstScreen's` `state` remains `1`, still satisfies the condition (`state==1`), executes navigation **again** for the **`2nd`** time
- NavHost `re-composes`
- `FirstScreen's` `state` remains `1`, satisfies the condition (`state==1`), executes navigation again for the **`3rd`** time
- and the cycle never ends..

Based on the official [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation),

> You should only call navigate() as part of a callback and not as part
> of your composable itself, to avoid calling navigate() on every
> recomposition.

I would advice considering `navigation` as a **one-time** event, doing it inside `LaunchedEffect` and observed from a `SharedFlow` emission. Below is a short workaround to your problem.

Have a sealed class `UiEvent`,

```
sealed class UiEvent {
    data class Navigate(val params: Any?): UiEvent()
}
```

modify your `ViewModel` like this

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    ...

    private val _oneTimeEvent = MutableSharedFlow<UiEvent>()
    val oneTimeEvent = _oneTimeEvent.asSharedFlow()

    ...

    fun navigate()  {
        if (_state.value == 1) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                _oneTimeEvent.emit(UiEvent.Navigate(1))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

, then observe it via `LaunchedEffect` in your `FirstScreen`

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(
    navigate: () -> Unit,
    ..
) {
    ...
    ...
    
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        mainViewModel.oneTimeEvent.collectLatest { uiEvent ->
            when (uiEvent) {
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                    navigate()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see  [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74174614/jetpack-compose-navigation-loads-screen-infinitely)