# Navigation is being called every time in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation, compose-recomposition

I'm implementing registration in my application and, after filling in the respective fields, I click on a button that will make a registration request to the API. Meanwhile, I place a Loading View and when I receive the successful response, I execute the navigation to the OnBoarding screen. The issue is that the navController is always running the navigation and doing the navigation and popUp several times, when it should only do it once. I always get this warning on logs: `Ignoring popBackStack to destination 29021787 as it was not found on the current back stack` and I am not able to do any click or focus in the OnBoardingScreen.

My code:

```
val uiState by registerViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

when (uiState) {
        is BaseViewState.Data -> {
            navController.navigate(NavigationItem.OnBoarding.route) {
                popUpTo(NavigationItem.Register.route) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
        }
        is BaseViewState.Loading -> LoadingView()
        is BaseViewState.Error -> BannerView()
        else -> {}
    }
```

On button click I call the viewModel like this:

```
registerViewModel.onTriggerEvent(
                    RegisterEvent.CreateUser(
                        usernameInputState.value.text,
                        emailInputState.value.text,
                        passwordInputState.value.text
                    )
                )
```

And, in ViewModel, I do my request like this:

```
override fun onTriggerEvent(eventType: RegisterEvent) {
        when (eventType) {
            is RegisterEvent.CreateUser -> createUser(eventType.username, eventType.email, eventType.password)
        }
    }

    private fun createUser(username: String, email: String, password: String) = safeLaunch {
        setState(BaseViewState.Loading)
        execute(createUser(CreateUser.Params(username, email, password))) {
            setState(BaseViewState.Data(RegisterViewState(it)))
        }
    }
```

I guess it should be caused by recomposition, because I put a breakpoint on first when scenario and it stops here multiple times, but only one on ViewModel. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is here

```
is BaseViewState.Data -> {
        navController.navigate(NavigationItem.OnBoarding.route) {
            popUpTo(NavigationItem.Register.route) {
                 inclusive = true
            }
        }
}
```

Every time you call `navController.navigate` NavHost will keep on passing through this block, executing an endless loop.

I suggest having the navigate call from a `LaunchedEffect` with a `key` (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74390705/viewmodel-triggered-navigation-with-jetpackcompose/74391028#74391028)),

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = "some key") {
     navController.navigate(…)
}
```

or creating a separate structure namely "Events" where they are emitted as `SharedFlow` and observed via a `Unit` keyed `LaunchedEffect`

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.event.collectLatest {
            when (it) {
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                    navController.navigate(…)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which is the best way? Adding the LaunchedEffect with key worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you and youre welcome. It depends though, personally I don't want to manage the `Key`, I'm confident and have a peace of mind knowing that the effect (LaunchedEffect) is only guaranteed to be executed only once since the key is `Unit`, and I have a data structure hierarchy where I consider them as "one-time-event" only

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I think I will follow the same approach, thank you.

Comment: It's not working, I tried with LaunchedEffect still its navigate to multiple times

Comment: Nobody can guess how your code is structured, it would be better to create an S.O post and including a reproducible code to see why its still firing on a LaunchedEffect