# Jetpack Compose Navigation endless loop

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation, compose-recomposition

I am trying to show a walkthrough of my app on initial start up.  I am trying to present 3 screens

Welcome
Screen1
Screen2

I have this navigation graph

```
composable(Routes.Welcome.name) {
   WelcomeScreen(
      done = {
         navController.navigate(Routes.Screen1.name)
      }
   )
}

composable(Routes.Screen1.name) {
   Screen1(
      done = {
         navController.navigate(Routes.Screen2.name) {
            popUpTo(Routes.Welcome.name)
         }
      }
   )
}

composable(Routes.Screen2.name) {
   Screen2(
      done = {
         navController.navigate(Routes.Screen3.name) {
            popUpTo(Routes.Welcome.name)
         }
      }
   )
}

composable(Routes.Screen3.name) {
   Screen1(
      done = {
         navController.navigate(Routes.Main.name)
      }
   )
}
```

However when I am done with Screen1 and I try to navigate to Screen2 I end up in an infinite loop with Screen1 done continuously being called while Screen2 is presented.

```
@Composable
fun Screen1(
   done: () -> Unit,
   viewModel: StartupViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
   val screen1 by viewModel.screen1.observeAsState()

   if (screen1 != true) {
         Button(onClick = { viewModel.setScreen1(true) }) {
            Text(text = "Go to screen 2")
         }
   } else {
      // once screen1 is set in viewmodel I should end up here.
      // let my parent handle navigation to next screen.
      done()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a similar issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74221538/jetpack-compose-mutable-state-causes-infinite-recomposition-when-navigating-wi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74174614/jetpack-compose-navigation-loads-screen-infinitely).

Based on the official [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation),

> You should only call navigate() as part of a callback and not as part
> of your composable itself, to avoid calling navigate() on every
> recomposition.

The culprit is in the entire `if-else` block.

```
val screen1 by viewModel.screen1.observeAsState() 

if (screen1 != true) {
    ...
 } else {
    ...
    done()
}
```

At first pass of composition, the `if{…}` block will execute, but when you update the `screen1` state it will satisfy the `else{…}` block calling your navigation, it will then call a `re-composition` of the `NavHost` which in turn call this composable again and because `screen1 != true` stills evaluate to `false` it will call the `else{…}` block again, now your navigation is on a vicious loop.

I would suggest doing this inside a `LaunchedEffect`.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74390705/viewmodel-triggered-navigation-with-jetpackcompose), the code in question looks closely similar to yours.